# View is not disposed after removing it from a region

Tags: c#, wpf, object, prism

Adding Tabs to an application I realize that my child views are not disposed (finalized) after I remove them from the `Region`.

```
 regionManager.Regions[regionName].Remove(tabItem.Content);
```

Everytime close the Tab and reopen it, a new instance is created correctly, but the old instance keeps open until I close the application. Checkt it via `Finalizer` Breakpoint. This causes my application not to release the `Region` and crash when `RegionManager` tries to create a region which already exists.

Even

```
 [RegionMemberLifetime(KeepAlive = false)]
```

will remove it from the `Region`, but the object is still alive.

Comment: Something somewhere still has a reference to the region (the Tab), which is why it's not getting disposed correctly.

Comment: Can you explain how this would be possible? You _remove_ the view from the region by calling `IRegion.Remove()`, but your view is still visible after that? Then it's not about disposing or finalizing, it's about removing a view from the region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and i just solved it this morning.

Just before adding the new Region with regionManager check if it doesn't already exist using:

```
this.regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("Your region name")
```

Then, when i remove the view from the region, i just invoke garbage collector GC.Collect() method to "Dispose" the removed views and free memory.

However make sure that you use the attribute **[RegionMemberLifetime(KeepAlive = false)]** on your view.

For more information, see [this post](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/397222)

### Edit

Another solution, using Disposable pattern that i use also for some views.

Where my view implement IDisposable interface, then the method looks as the following:

```
public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  
        }
```

After that, when you remove the view from the Region, just invoke Dispose method :

```
myRegion.Deactivate(view);
myRegion.Remove(view);

var disposable = view as IDisposable;
if (disposable != null)
{
    disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Note that i'm using mvvm pattern, and i don't have to free any another managed object, Otherwise, if you have some managed objects inside your view, please see more about [IDisposable pattern here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you are saying - even the GC.Collect() - but the reference is still in use and the instance does not get disposed. How do I figure out where it is in use?

Comment: @JohannesWanzek 
1) how do you do to test that? 
2) Are you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: @JohannesWanzek I just reviewed my code, i can confirm that after removing the View from the region and calling GC.Collect() the instance disposed ( i tested that by using your method Breakpoint on the finalizer). 

You may call Region.Desactivate(view) before remove it.